# Show posts based on child custom taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom CPT called cinema which bears a custom taxonomy called "cinema-city" where we can add cities and district as sub-child. I want to show or loop cinema in a way that the City should show once, then its children "districts" and then all cinema's under those child cats of the city. 
In the image attached you can see the rough idea of what I want to achieve;
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRM72.jpg).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Mueed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

get_terms function arguments can be found here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/

get_posts function arguments can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

```
// Get top level cities
$cities = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'cinema-city'
));

// Loop cities
foreach($cities as $city){

    // Output city html

    // Get all child districts by using 'child_of' argument
    $districts = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'cinema-city',
        'child_of' => $city->term_id
    ));

    // Loop the child districts
    foreach($districts as $district){

    // Output distruct output

        // Get all posts of thad 
        $cinemas = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'cinema',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'taxonomy' => 'cinema-city',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $district->term_id
            )
        ));

        // Loop over the cinemas
        foreach($cinemas as $cinema){

            // Output cinema output

        }

    }

}
```